# How to design a database for configuration items?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

To do: a configuration management database for a network.

My solution: I organized the database in Configuration Items, Relations and Attributes. At first I have a table of Configuration Items, a table of Relations and a table of Attributes. I want to offer the user the maximum freedom of choice so I do not put all configuration items in one table. They have a number of common fields but they also have a significant number of different fields.

[image: Configuration Management Database]

Problem: how can I avoid having too many tables ? and how can I avoid the situation when for a Configuration Item Table I have a foreign key that has the same value for the entire table ? Like in the C.I. Type Field of C.I 1 Table. It will have the same value for the entire column.